# How can I call particleJS after some time?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I'm using particlesJS for creating a page.
I use it as a background, but here is the thing, I want to show the particlesJS animation after 10 seconds after the page loads. I can't do #particle-js display:none for 10 secs, because all my content will be hidden for 10 sec, and I don't want to hide the content but the animation itself. I guess I should use setTimeout to the app.js file or something, but I don't know how to, I'm noobie with JS. TY GUYS!

```
<div id="particles-js"> ALL WEBSITE CONTENT </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/particles.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
and app.js file: 
particlesJS('particles-js', {animations};);
```

Comment: setTimeout(function(){  //code here }, 10000);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this

```
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            //code here 
            particlesJS('particles-js', {animations};);
        }, 10000);
})
```

when the page is loaded, the 10 seconds start.

p.s. 1000 ms = 1 second -> 10000 ms = 10 seconds